# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, eclipse, illegalargumentexception

I'm less than a beginner in Java (I'm a .NET developer), but i have to fix a Java error when invoking a WebMethod through a proxy class.
From .NET, I can call it with no problems, but in Java, this is what happens:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at weblogic.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser.endElement(SAXParser.java:1411)
    at weblogic.apache.xerces.validators.common.XMLValidator.callEndElement(XMLValidator.java:1613)
    at weblogic.apache.xerces.framework.XMLDocumentScanner$ContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentScanner.java:1174)
    at weblogic.apache.xerces.framework.XMLDocumentScanner.parseSome(XMLDocumentScanner.java:399)
    at weblogic.apache.xerces.framework.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:1147)
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.WebLogicXMLReader.parse(WebLogicXMLReader.java:135)
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLReader.parse(RegistryXMLReader.java:147)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:796)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.verizon.vmw.csgw.ws.updateDOJob.v4_4.wsdl.UpdateDOJobServiceSoapBindingStub.updateDOJob(UpdateDOJobServiceSoapBindingStub.java:206)
    at com.verizon.vmw.csgw.ws.updateDOJob.v4_4.wsdl.UpdateDOJobServiceProxy.updateDOJob(UpdateDOJobServiceProxy.java:50)
    at rm.interfaces.wfadosnd.WfaDoSndWorker.updateDOJobComments(WfaDoSndWorker.java:1111)
    at rm.interfaces.wfadosnd.WfaDoSndWorker.checkEtaAsgn(WfaDoSndWorker.java:507)
    at rm.interfaces.wfadosnd.WfaDoSndWorker.resequenceDODispatches(WfaDoSndWorker.java:541)
    at rm.interfaces.wfadosnd.WfaDoSndWorker.processOutboundRows(WfaDoSndWorker.java:283)
    at rm.interfaces.wfadosnd.WfaDoSndWorker.run(WfaDoSndWorker.java:112)
    at rm.util.WorkerThread.run(ThreadPool.java:152)
```

Does anyone have any idea of what could be causing this exception?

Comment: can we see some code of where the error is happening?

Comment: Stack trace is rarely enough to identify an error with that vague of a description. Could use more detail.

Comment: _call.invoke(new java.lang.Object[] {requestMsg})   THIS IS THE LINE THROWING THE ERROR MESSAGE. I think I figured out what it is but i don't know how to fix it. The Request Class has a String[] member (ArrayOfString), and i googled it and it's a very common error when deserializing String[] members. This is an example: http://www1e77.opensubscriber.com/message/axis-user@ws.apache.org/7855953.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with Wireshark what goes over the wire and diff the .NET request with the java request.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your web application was receiving a message, and one of its fields failed verification that it was the right type (or acceptable value).

Whether that was a data issue, or a coding issue depends heavily on the data, code, and intent which are all not provided.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the class names in the stack trace, the exception is thrown during deserialization of the webservice response.

The exception itself is pretty generic and hence carries little useful information.

Try looking at the response sent over the wire, or set an exception breakpoint in eclipse so you can inspect the stack frames the exception is thrown to get additional context. (To ease interpretation of what went wrong, you'll probably want to procure the source code of your web service stack).

Answer (score 0):

look in the code for something is parsed for user input

like this `Integer  i = Integer.parseInt("string");`

and the "string" contains none valid number